# Thread Safe ofstream access

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm attempting to design a thread-safe unordered_map containing ofstreams. Is this implementation valid? Worker threads will lock the streams write to it, and then call the unlock function.

```
class ThreadSafeStreamMap
{
public:
    ThreadSafeStreamMap() :
        m_map(),
        m_locks()
    {}
    ~ThreadSafeStreamMap() {}

    std::ofstream& lockStream(const std::string& instrument, const uint32_t& apid)
    {
        auto& mut = getMutex(apid);
        mut.lock();
        auto& stream = getStream(apid);
        if (stream.is_open())
        {
            return stream;
        }
        else
        {
            stream.open("output/" + instrument + "_" + std::to_string(apid) + ".txt", std::ios::ate);
            return stream;
        }
    }

    void unlockStream(const uint32_t& apid)
    {
          auto& mut = getMutex(apid);
          mut.unlock();
    }

    std::mutex& getMutex(const uint32_t& apid)
    {
         return m_locks[apid];
    }

    std::ofstream& getStream(const uint32_t& apid)
    {
         return m_map[apid];
    }

private:
    std::unordered_map<uint32_t, std::ofstream> m_map;
    std::unordered_map<uint32_t, std::mutex> m_locks;
};
```

Comment: It isn't a *thread-safe map* because insertion/retrieval is not locked. It's just a map of streams and locks. It is also not nice as users need to unlock manually. Returning a handle (by value) that is both a stream and a lock that unlocks as it goes out of scope would be a nicer interface IMHO.

Comment: So I should lock in the getStream and getMutex functions?

Comment: Yes you would need to lock them. But why have two separate maps? Store a pair of (stream, mutex).